# gcc compile error on simple code

Tags: c, gcc, compilation

I need help with a simple `c` structure and can't find it why it's not compiling using `gcc` (opensuse 11.4)

I have this code:

```
struct Image {
 int w;
 int h;
 // other code
};
```

in the same file I have another struct array like this:

```
struct ShapeImage
{
  Image image[10];
  // other code
};
```

when I compile I get:

```
syntax error before [' token`
```

Why I am getting this error if is specify the number 10 in the image
the `image[10];` looks good to me, what is wrong?

Comment: C, or C++?  If the former, it's `struct Image image[10];`

Comment: We need to see more code. What is the complete description of the error? Are these structs in the same file? Is the `Image` before `ShapeImage`? Etc.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

It should be:

```
struct Image image[10] ;
```

Or use typedef while defining the struct:

```
typedef struct {
 int w;
 int h;
 // other code
} Image;
```

And use the code otherwise same as in your question.